# UML enumeration as a return type

Tags: uml

`<< enumeration>> E1  | .RED .GREEN .BLUE |`

I have the above as an enumeration class in a UML diagram. I associate it with another class say `House`. I now need a method on `House` say `+getColor()` which returns a color from the above enumeration.

How would I depict this in UML?
would it be like : `+getColor(): E1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your suggestion is right and depending on the level of detail, you could also add dependency from House to E1.